# Evangelion - What happened to the humans in space/astronauts during the 3rd impact?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

Well, title says it all. What happened to all the humans in space (and maybe under the sea) when the 3rd impact happened and Rei became that giant human thing and all the souls of everyone on the surface of the Earth seemed to merge with her?

I couldn't quite recall if I saw any red "links" from space or from anything under the surface of the sea. I'm also pretty sure that it's safe to assume that there are astronauts in the Eva Universe cuz they have big Eva mechs.

Comment: I don't think it's as safe as you think to assume there are humans in space.Putting people in space is very expensive and requires a political will that might be lacking in the post-Second Impact world, especially with so many resources apparently going to the Eva program.

Comment: So it's then safe to assume that there was no astronauts post-Second Impact?

Comment: I don't remember any evidence either way in the series, so there might be. But Second Impact killed two billion people right away and caused climate shifts and rising ocean levels worldwide. In a scenario like that, space travel is the last thing most governments would want to spend money on. So I don't think we can assume there were astronauts.

Comment: Quite sure Space Exploration comes second to anti-Angel Weapons Development.....though that being said in Rebuild there is that Moon Base where Kaworu was seen hanging about in the second movie but Rebuild, at the moment, appears to be a different universe